# OData sorting by GUID column not working

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to query an OData endpoint using *WCF OData Service* and return the entities ordered by a *GUID* column.

When I execute the following statement

```
var employees = odataService.Employees
    .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
    .ToList();
```

*odataService* is the proxy class generated by WCF.

I get the expected entities but they're not ordered. They're returned in the order they were introduced in the database.

i.e.

```
70c63a41-a1a8-4cd0-be9e-685aa6a1df1e
90bc0ba7-9dc3-411c-abe4-845ace740b32
588e4b3c-9ad9-40a1-89da-fe39765e4d03
```

The URL generated by the LINQ statement is the following:

http://localhost:21157/odata/Employees()?$orderby=ID

How can I get the entities ordered by the GUID column?

Thank you.

Comment: I've done some tests with the same query ordering by another properties (of type string and integer) and the result is indeed ordered so the problem is with the type **GUID**

Comment: You've tagged this with asp.net-web-api, but then talk about WCF. They are not the same...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan because the OData endpoint is exposed through Web API